# Android Bluetooth connectiong using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord or createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord On a Samsung Device Android 7

Tags: android, bluetooth, sdk

i have some problems connecting to a bluetooth device with all Samsung Galaxy devices with android 6 or 7.
The same code is working on other Devices with Android 7 , like a HTC M9 for example.

My Code so far:

```
         try {
            adapter.cancelDiscovery();

            socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(btUuid);
            socket.connect();

            publishProgress(context.getString(R.string.bt_con_established));

            int r;
            byte[] s = new byte[256];
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while(!isCancelled() && (r = in.read(s)) != -1) {
                publishProgress(new String(s, 0, r));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(!isCancelled()) {
                return context.getString(R.string.bt_con_error);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if(socket != null) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return context.getString(R.string.bt_con_not_closed);
            }
        }
```

I always receive a isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy.

Someone have a idea, why this is only not working on Samsung devices?
Are there some special Security rules on Samsung or KNOX devices?

I also used the UUID 0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB with the same error.

Many Thanks